# Displaying a string while using cond in Lisp

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp

I'm just starting off with Lisp and need some help.  This is technically homework, but I gave it a try and am getting somewhat what I wanted:

```
(defun speed (kmp)  
  (cond ((> kmp 100) "Fast")    
        ((< kmp  40) "Slow") 
        (t           "Average")))
```

However, if I run the program it displays `"Average"` instead of just `Average` (without the quotes).

How can I get it to display the string without quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use symbols instead of strings:

```
(defun speed (kmp)  
  (cond ((> kmp 100) 'fast)    
        ((< kmp  40) 'slow) 
        (t           'average)))
```

Symbols are uppercased by default, so internally fast is then FAST.

You can write any symbol in any case and with any characters using escaping with vertical bars:

```
|The speeed is very fast!|
```

Above is a valid symbol in Common Lisp and is stored internally just as you write it with case preserved.

Answer (score 3):

You can use symbols instead of strings. But keep in mind that symbols will be converted to uppercase:

```
> 'Average
AVERAGE
```

If you care about case or want to embed spaces, use `format`:

```
 > (format t "Average")
 Average
```

Answer (score 2):

The read-eval-print loop displays the return value of your function, which is one of the strings in a cond branch. Strings are printed readably by surrounding them with double-quotes.

You could use (write-string (speed 42)). Don't worry that it also shows the string in double-quotes - that's the return value of write-string, displayed after the quoteless output.